# Mysterious First Responder change

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, first-responder

I'm currently working on a Preference Pane. I would like a custom NSView subclass to have First Responder status upon launch of my Preference Pane. I set my view to be first responder as such (within my NSPreferencePane subclass):

```
- (void)didSelect {
    NSLog(@"Before: %@", self.mainView.window.firstResponder);

    [self.keyboardView.window makeFirstResponder:self.keyboardView];

    NSLog(@"After: %@", self.mainView.window.firstResponder);
}
```

I periodically check the current First Responder thereafter, and it seems that shortly after didSelect finishes, the First Responder is changed to the mainView of my NSPreferencePane. Nothing in my program is causing this change. Here is the output:

```
Before: <NSTextView: 0x60000013dce0>
//presumably the System Preferences search field.
After: <AMKeyboardView: 0x608000321a40>
//successfully set to the desired AMKeyboardView.
<NSView: 0x61000013ea00>
//<--- magic change to mainView, for seemingly no reason.
```

In Interface Builder, my window has an outlet called initialFirstResponder. I can't set this outlet to anything, because my view is added programatically, and isn't accessible by Interface Builder. I suspect the lack of connection is leading to a default behaviour which sets the first responder to the mainView.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: And why exactly would you like a `UIView` to be first responder?

Comment: It's an `NSView` subclass that accepts keyboard input. (implements keyDown)

Comment: Oh, OSX territory, can't help you with that.

Comment: Can you implement `becomeFirstResponder` in your main view and put a breakpoint to see why it's being called?

Comment: This is the stack trace from that mysterious call http://cl.ly/image/450f220n3a3W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source code the [Secrets Preference Pane](http://secrets.blacktree.com/), I found the method by which they set their own search box as the first responder when the preference pane is opened. I applied this method to my own pref pane by adding to my `didSelect` method:

```
[self.mainView.window performSelector:@selector(makeFirstResponder:)
                           withObject:self.keyboardView
                           afterDelay:0.0];
```

...and it works! However, I have no idea **why** it works. I assume the 0.0 delay isn't actually truly instant, which makes this performSelector run after the mysterious first responder change has occurred.

I suppose this answers my question, but leads to a new one: why does this work?

Comment: I would not investigate so much on something like this. If there's one thing I've learned in years of Mac programming, is that the stuff that Apple does is always unpredictable.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Haha glad this could help, all these years layer. I would just suggest you increase that `0.0` to like `0.01` or something, because the `0.0` probably leads to less reliable behavior